# Modify Many-to-Many table Created By EF5 Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have 2 classes and the one is a collection property of the other like below.

```
public class NotificationMessage
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}

public class Device
{
    public int ID  { get; set; }
    public string Token  { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NotificationMessage> NotificationMessages { get; set; }
}

public class NotificationMessageDevice
{
    [Column(Order = 0), Key, ForeignKey("NotificationMessage")]
    public int NotificationMessageID { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1), Key, ForeignKey("Device")]
    public int DeviceID { get; set; }


    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
    public virtual NotificationMessage NotificationMessage { get; set; }
}
```

When you create a relationship like above, the entity flamework is enough clever to create many to many relationship on Database by creating NotificationMessageDevices.

The problem rises in here. Now I want to add CreateDate to the table 'NotificationMessageDevices' . What I have done is that I have created a new class called 'NotificationMessageDevice' in the way entity framework would create the table "NotificationMessageDevices" in existing database. I added new properties and called Update-Verbose. The very first exception was about missing ID property it wanted me to add public int ID {get;set;} however when I add this up it realizes the ID property is index property so that I need to remove all the data in that table.

What is the workaround of this case on Entity Framework without data loss :)

Comment: Are you trying to use code-first migrations?

Comment: Not actually a migration. I have created my database with code-first from the scratch. But I realized that for many-to-many relationships EF creates a new table to hold the data. Now I want to add another column into that linker table.

Comment: Be it that you are changing the db you will have to do some sort of migration, but to get round the ID property make a compound key in your linker table. i.e. add attribute [Key, Column(Order=1)] and [Key, Column(Order=2)] respectively to the ID properties of the linker table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the link entity like this:

```
public class DeviceNotificationMessages
{
    public DeviceNotificationMessages()
    {
        CreateDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    }

    [Column(Order = 0), Key, ForeignKey("NotificationMessage")]
    public int NotificationMessageId { get; set; }
    public virtual NotificationMessage NotificationMessage { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 1), Key, ForeignKey("Device")]
    public int DeviceID { get; set; }
    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

You'd then need to handle the migration to this new entity yourself to avoid data loss.  If you're using code-first migrations, you'll need to add a manual migration (automatic migration WILL result in data loss) and then edit the script so that the data isn't deleted.

Comment: when i do it like this several errors are occurring   \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'NotificationMessageDevice' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'NotificationMessageDevices' is based on type 'NotificationMessageDevice' that has no keys defined.

Comment: It is now giving the following error The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.NotificationMessageDevices' and the index name 'PK_dbo.NotificationMessageDevices'. The duplicate key value is (0, 0).

Comment: Post the code you're using for NotificationMessageDevices in your original question please.

Comment: Doesn't look like you changed your relationships on the Device and Notification entities - these need to point to your link entity, not directly.  I know this makes it harder to use, but it's the only way to get properties onto a many-to-many relationship that I know of.

Comment: What I have realized is that whenever i use Update-Database -Verbose after the modifications, it tries to create new table NotificationMessageDevices1.

Comment: I said initially that you would NOT be able to use automatic migrations with this.  You'll need to add a manual migration (e.g. Add-Migration AddNotificationMessageDeviceLink) and edit the code it generates in order to prevent your data loss.  Otherwise you'll lose the data in your existing link table (once you change the navigation properties at each end).

Comment: I have solved my problem by modifying property names into Device_ID and NotificationMessage_ID. By the way I have used Automatic migration and It avoided data loss :)